# Contouring Qualitative Gridded Data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have gridded data (the output of a `label` function) and am looking to contour (not filled contour) the various labeled regions efficiently with different colors with `matplotlib`. For example, imagine that I generate a labeled dataset by:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage

test_arr = np.zeros((30,30))
test_arr[2:10, 2:10] = 2
test_arr[18:24, 18:24] = 2
label = skimage.measure.label(test_arr>1)
```

What I want is to plot contour lines around the labeled regions (with different colors) on top of the underlying data, e.g., something like this:

[image: contour lines around different labeled data]

To generate that, I used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.pcolormesh(test_arr)
plt.colorbar()
plt.contour(label == 1, levels=[1,], colors='r')
plt.contour(label==2, levels = [1,], colors = 'b')
```

Clearly this (mostly) works, however, when there are thousands of labels, this is quite inefficient. Contouring all labels with the same color is possible by:

```
plt.pcolormesh(test_arr)
plt.colorbar()
plt.contour(label, levels=[0.9], colors='r')
```

and this is reasonably efficient. However, this does not allow for multiple colors. When adding multiple levels, it contours every level, for example:

```
plt.pcolormesh(test_arr)
plt.colorbar()
plt.contour(label, levels=[0.9, 1.9], colors=['r', 'b'])
```

[image: extra contour lines around all data]

So, my question is, how do I do this efficiently?

Comment: Why is thousands of labels inefficient?  I don't think calling contour 1000 times will be that much slower than calling contour once with 1000 contour levels.   If you are worried about typing, just use a for-loop: `for i in range(1000): plt.contour(label==i)`

Comment: Calling contour thousands of times *is* substantially slower than calling `plt.contour` with thousands of levels. A quick test with 5000 levels is 1.74s calling `plt.contour(label, levels = np.arange(0, 5000, 1))` and 52s calling `for i in range(5000): plt.contour(label ==i)`.